# How to fourth layer to tensor to let convolution consume it

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to add preprocessing layers to a tensorflow model but can't figure out how to use tf.keras.layers.Reshape correctly.

I have some previous preprocessing layers that bring a numpy image to a tensorflow tensor of shape `TensorShape([50, 50, 3])`.

The first layer of the model that I am trying to connect these preprocessing layers to is a convolutional layer which requires a four dimensional input. When I call the model on a tensor of dimensions `Tensorshape([50,50,3])`, with three dimensions, I get the error:

```
Input 0 of layer "Conv1" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. 
Full shape received: (50, 50, 3)

Call arguments received by layer "model_1" (type Functional):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(50, 50, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```

Changing the input tensor to a numpy array and sizing it to a (1,50,50,3) array, then inputting that into the model works fine. I want to do this with a tensorflow layer however so that I can save the preprocessing and model inference into a single Saved Model format tensorflow file without having to do python preprocessing.

`tf.expand_dims(input_tensor, axis=0)` works, but it's not a layer object so I can't use it. It looks like `tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,50,50,3), input_shape=(50,50,3))` or `tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,50,50,3))` is the way to go then.

My silly problem is that I just can't figure out how to use `tf.keras.layers.Reshape`, even using the tf/keras documentation.
When I pass in a tensor of dimensions `TensorShape([50, 50, 3])`, to `tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,50,50,3))` I get the error message:

```
Input to reshape is a tensor with 7500 values, but the requested shape has 375000 [Op:Reshape]

Call arguments received by layer "reshape_9" (type Reshape):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(50, 50, 3), dtype=float32)
```

So, how do I get this to work? All I want is to end up with the same Tensor as inputted but with `TensorShape([1,50,50,3])` instead of `TensorShape([50,50,3])`, and I want this to happen with a tf.keras.layers object. So really I just want to perform an identity transformation that adds a fourth dimension of size one at the beginning of a tensor so that a convolutional layer can consume it, and I want this from a tf.keras.layers object.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the images are put together into batches.
Try

```
tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1,50,50,3))
```

Or you can use a Lambda layer instead:

```
tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1))
```

The value -1 means the `reshape` or `expand_dims` function will calculate that shape dimension for you, depending on the number of values it receives.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to add an extra dimension for the batch size, if you are passing in a single image the batch size would be 1. You can use `np.expand_dims` to add the extra dimension.